# Do (a+b)mod n=a'+b' as same as (a+b) mod n= (a'+b') mod n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

The question is:Let n be a fixed postive integer greater than 1.If a mod n= a' and b mod n =b',prove that (a + b) mod n= (a' + b') mod n and (ab) mod n= (a'b') mod n.

My answer so far is:From defination of modulus, a mod n then there have a integer k,so that a= n k + a'
And,b mod n then there have a integer v,so that b=n v + b'

Therefore,(a +b) = (k+v) n + a'+b', give us (a+b) mod n = (a'+b')

But the question is asking prove  (a + b) mod n= (a' + b') mod n.

How can I turn (a+b) mod n = (a'+b') to (a + b) mod n= (a' + b') mod n ?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: find the (unique!) $\tilde{a}\in\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ such that $a=\tilde{a}+kn$ and $a^\prime = \tilde{a}+k^\prime n$.

Comment: Does mod stands to calculate remainder or like a congruence relation?

Comment: mod stands to calculate remainder. a mod n = r,means r is remainder when dividing a by n.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a [complete residue system mod $n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_residue_system_modulo_m#Residue_systems), so I'll stick to that.  Thus, the "$\mathrm{mod}$" operator returns an integer in $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$.

> Therefore, $(a+b) = (k+v)n + a'+b'$, give us $(a+b)\ \mathrm{mod}\ n = (a'+b')$.

This implication is where you went wrong.  As a counterexample, $$(4+5)\ \mathrm{mod}\ 6=3$$ whereas $$4\ \mathrm{mod}\ 6+5\ \mathrm{mod}\ 6=9.$$

Instead, you should be trying to show

> $(a + b)\ \mathrm{mod}\ n = (a' + b')\ \mathrm{mod}\ n$

that is

> $(a + b)\ \mathrm{mod}\ n = (a\ \mathrm{mod}\ n + b\ \mathrm{mod}\ n)\ \mathrm{mod}\ n$.

Comment: thanks for yourcomment. yes.I know this this formula.But, then the answer will become (a+b)mod n = (a mod n +b mod n) mod n = (a'+b') mod n. I don't think we can just put that in the formula, becuase that will become too easy.I think the question ask some prove on why "(a+b)mod n =(a'+b') mod n"

Comment: (This really should be a "too easy" problem.  It would be much easier to work in $\mathbb{Z}_n$.)  I've left the writing of the proof for you.  We essentially just pull out a factor of n and leave a remainder in $\{0,1,\ldots,n-1\}$ everywhere.